# Получение конкретного id из массива выводимого в цикле если данные пришли из бд

Tags: php, база-данных, циклы

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть цикл для вывода заявок:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $num_result; $i++){
$orders_catalog = pg_fetch_array($ord_result);

$order_id = $orders_catalog['order_id'];
$ord_name = $orders_catalog['feature_name'];
$user_name = $orders_catalog['user_name'];
$user_email = $orders_catalog['e_mail'];
$user_phone = $orders_catalog['phone'];
$subcategory_id = $orders_catalog['sub_name'];
$datetime = $orders_catalog['datetime'];
$message = $orders_catalog['message'];

?>
<div class = "forsinglereq">
        <div id = "servname"><span id = "inservname">НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ УСЛУГИ:</span><?php echo $ord_name;?></div><br>
        <span class = "prefix">Имя:</span> <div class = "inform"><?php echo $user_name;?></div><br>
        <span class = "prefix">Email:</span> <div class = "inform"><?php echo $user_email;?></div><br>
        <span class = "prefix">Телефон:</span> <div class = "inform"><?php echo $user_phone;?></div><br>
        <span class = "prefix">Подкатегория услуги:</span> <div class = "inform"><?php echo $subcategory_id;?></div><br>

        <span class = "prefix">Дата и время заявки:</span> <div class = "inform"><?php echo $datetime;?></div><br>
        <span id = "message">Сообщение:</span> <div id = "comment"><?php echo $message;?></div><br>

            <form action = "./rej_acc_funcs.php" method = "post">
              <div id = "accept"><label id = "acceptoo" for = "on">Принять</label></div>
              <div id = "reject"><label id = "rejectoo" for = "out">Отклонить</label></div>
                <input id = "on" type = "submit" name = "acceptreq">
                <input id = "out" type = "submit" name = "rejectreq">
                    <input type = "hidden" name = "orderid" value = "<?php echo $order_id;?>">
            </form>

    </div>
```

Как взять из цикла именно нужный мне массив для того, чтобы отклонить или принять заявку? Пока из таблицы выбирается первая запись. В обработчик передаю id. Но я не знаю как передать конкретный id. Когда есть возможность передать по ссылкам методом GET - нет проблем. Но здесь весь массив я достаю из таблицы sql запросом. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что с помощью приведенной разметки выводится список заявок, один `div class = "forsinglereq"` - одна заявка? И проблема заключается в том, как определить, для какой заявки сработал сабмит?

Comment: Совершенно верно, Ponio.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `data`-атрибуты. 
php&HTML:

```
<?php 
$order_id = $orders_catalog['order_id']; ?>
<input id = "on" type = "submit" data-order="<?= $order_id?>" name = "acceptreq">
<input id = "out" type = "submit" data-order="<?= $order_id?>" name = "rejectreq">
```

javascript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("on");
console.log(elem.dataset.order);
```

В JQuery можно использовать метод `data()`.
Еще о `data`-атрибутах: [Свойство dataset и data-атрибуты](https://learn.javascript.ru/attributes-and-custom-properties#%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-dataset-data-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B).

Comment: Не разбираюсь я в jQuery. Но, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Или вам нужен чистый php? Вот тут способ с использованием `hidden`-элементов: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286184/access-html-5-data-attribute-in-php Или использовать `php`-метод `getAttribute`.

Comment: Я не против учиться js. Просто постоянно чего-то не доделываю и у меня js не работает. Изначально я передаю в обработчик id заявки через input hidden. В обработчике принимаю $id = $_POST['имя хиддена']. Только все равно выбирается первая запись из таблицы бд :-((

Comment: Имя `hidden`-элемента одинаковое для всех заявок? Тогда, конечно, будет выбираться только первый. Попробуйте каждому `submit` прописать атрибут с номером заявки, затем его значение считывать с помощью `getAttribute`.

Comment: Копаюсь в документации, только не пойму как конкретно прописать атрибут с номером заявки для submit  и потом считать -((

Comment: Насчет атрибутов была не уверена, нашла, что они не передаются браузером при отправке формы. Как вариант, сделать одно `hidden` поле и джаваскриптом менять его значение на выбранный `order` перед отправкой формы.